# How can I make links crawlable in a responsive menu on a webpage?

Tags: html, web, responsive-design, lighthouse

When I create a responsive menu on a webpage according to the really nice template at *[How TO - Responsive Top Navigation](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)*, Google [Lighthouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Lighthouse) claims that the links are not crawlable.

How can I make the links crawlable?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, while I did not find out whether this is actually a weakness of Lighthouse, I did find an example which shows how the responsive menu can be done without this error:

*[Responsive Navigation Menu Bar In HTML & CSS](https://codecary.com/responsive-navigation-menu-bar-in-html-css/)*

When putting the example code in this place on a web server, Lighthouse will find all links crawlable.

Answer (score 0):

The links in that example are not crawlable because they are either fragment identifier links (`#contact`) or JavaScript links (`javascript:void(0);`).  It has nothing to do with the responsiveness of the menu or any of the CSS involved.

To make the menu crawlable replace the links with links to HTML documents on your site.  For example:

```html
<a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
```

Comment: I did replace the #contact etc. links with links like the one you mentioned. But the issue seems to be that the links are hidden behind the a.icon element which only gets displayed after executing the javascript to open the navigation bar. So, hidden behind the javascript. So, how can that be avoided?

Comment: There is nothing hidden behind JavaScript as far as I can tell.  All the links are directly in the source code.

Comment: Not sure why they use an `<a>` for the hamburger menu.  I'd recommend replacing that with a clickable div which wouldn't need the `javascript:void(0);` href.